# Ajax form submission error using PHP Mailer

Tags: php, ajax, submit

I implemented this http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/jquery-plugins/jquery-ajaxsubmit.php tutorial on my form, and the form works successfully and displays the thank you div on submission. But the problem is I don't receieve any email, seems like PHP mailer is not working.

Please see the code below

```
    <?php
// Insert your email/web addresses and correct paths
$mailto = 'adil@adilsaleem.co.uk' ;
$from = "web@city.com" ;
$formurl = "http://astonstorlin.co.uk/citycoaches3/formmail.php" ;
$errorurl = "http://astonstorlin.co.uk/citycoaches3/error.php" ;
$thankyouurl = "http://astonstorlin.co.uk/citycoaches3/thankyou.php" ;

// Place Your Form info here...
$pickuppoint = ($_POST['pickuppoint']);
$destination = ($_POST['destination']);

// Check If Empty

// Add more Validation/Cleaning here...

// Place your Corresponding info here...
$message =

    "Pick Point: $pickuppoint\n\n" .
    "Destination: $destination\n\n" . 
    "noppl: $noppl\n\n" 
;

// Leave Alone
mail($mailto, $from, $message,
    "From: \"$name\" <$email>" . $headersep . "Reply-To: \"$name\" <$email>" . $headersep );
header( "Location: $thankyouurl" );
exit ;

?>
```

Comment: Check your php.ini configuration relating to SMTP, and your error logs, and post both here if you're still stuck.  Also, tell us if you can run the php and receive an email without using the AJAX call.

Comment: it seems you are using default php mail function not PHP Mailer

Answer (score 0):

I think your headers are not working. $headersep is not defined and moreover please follow :

```
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Example copied from http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php you can refer for more reading this link.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a shared hosting for example, sometimes they require you to use a fifth parameter like additional_parameters.

```
mail('nobody@example.com', 'the subject', 'the message', null,'-fwebmaster@example.com');
```

Check example 3 here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for all your help people, much appreciated.

I got the script working by deleting

```
"From: \"$name\" <$email>" . $headersep . "Reply-To: \"$name\" <$email>" . $headersep );
```

And the script started working. I have tried using other HTML php mailer but them don't seem to work with this tutorial example for some reason.http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/jquery-plugins/jquery-ajaxsubmit.php